# Get fixture data using sinon.fakeServer

Tags: javascript, testing, backbone.js, jasmine, sinon

I am trying to simulate Backbone.Model.fetch request using `sinon.fakeServer` or `sinon.useFakeXMLHttpRequest` and require.js.

Here's my piace of code which is not working properly (1)

My question is:
how can I get the fixture data using sinon.fakeServer?
Please the two comments at the end of this piece of code.

P.S.:
If I make the fetch request commenting the code about sinon.fakeServer, it makes the get request to the server.
If I make the get request using sinon.fakeServer it does not fetch anything (both server and fixture)

---

(1)

```
define([
    'js/models/myModel',
    'js/spec/fixtures/myModel.fixture'
], function (MyModel) {

            beforeEach(function () {

        this.myModel = new MyModel();

                console.log("fixtures", this.fixtures.Task, this);
                this.fixture = this.fixtures.Task.valid;
                this.fixtureTask = this.fixture.response;
                this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
                this.server.respondWith(
                    "GET",
                    Routing.generate("api_get_tasks"),
                    JSON.stringify(this.fixture)
                );
            });

            afterEach(function () {
                this.server.restore();
            });


            it("should make the correct request", function() {
                this.server.respond();

                this.feeds.fetch();

            console.log(this.fixture); // this response is OK
            console.log(this.myModel.attributes); // it does not take the value from this.fixture

            console.log("fixtures", this.fixtures.Task, this); // see the picture below

             });

});
```

[image]

Comment: `console.log("fixtures", this.fixtures.Task, this);`
What is output?

Comment: @user1248256 I responded you attaching a picture.

Answer (score 1):

You don't call the `fetch` method on the model.

Try this:

```
 it("should make the correct request", function() {
        this.myModel.fetch();
        this.server.respond();
        console.log(this.fixture); // this response is OK
        console.log(this.myModel.attributes); // it does not take the value from this.fixture

        console.log("fixtures", this.fixtures.Task, this); // fixtures  Object  jasmine.Spec

 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did it, but the result does not change. Anyway, if I try to make this.myModel.fetch(); then the result is the `defaults: {}` which is in the model definition and not in `fixture`.

Comment: Hm. Did you try `success` and `error` callbacks to the `fetch` method call in order to see a response from `sinon.fakeServer`? 
`this.myModel.fetch({success: function (m, resp) {console.log('success: %o, %o', m, resp)}, error: function (m, resp) {console.log('error: %o, %o', m, resp)});`
It seems you should use `this.fixtures.Task.valid.response` rather than `this.fixtures.Task.valid` for the response, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @LorraineBernard Or maybe you can show MyModel prototype? Did you implement a `parse` function?

Comment: Making this.myModel.fetch({success or error or complete... I don't have any result. Probably because I am using sinon.fakeServer. Do you know another way to get the response from the sinon.fakeServer? Thanks

Comment: @LorraineBernard Show the example: http://jsfiddle.net/SCZu9/2/
the `fetch` callbacks are fired when the `sinon.fakeServer` respond is called.

Comment: @LorraineBernard  I've seen you've updated the question. But your `this.feeds.fetch();` must be before `this.server.respond();`, because obviously a request goes earlier than a respond.